# Image viewer showing one thumb per folder for Windows

Tags: image-viewer

I need an image viewer capable of showing thumbs for folders, but showing only the thumb of the first image in each folder, not thumbs with a mix of images in those folders, like the Windows Explorer is showing.
If possible, would be awesome if the viewer would allow me to set for each folder which image in that folder would be shown as the thumb of that folder (instead of the first image in the folder) and to save that configuration in a configuration file, so I can use it on another computer too.
Would be very nice if the viewer would allow em to set the size of the thumbs (all thumbs the same size, of course).

If possible, I am looking for a free viewer capable of doing this.

I remember I've found such a viewer some years ago but I can't remember it's name now. I think it was a viewer that was available for Linux and MacOS too.

Comment: I seem to remember that either IrfanView or xnView can do what you specify your first sentence and can also set the size.  I'm not sure which one, or if I am remembering correctly.  Both are free if you want to try.

Comment: For which Operating System?

Comment: irfanview is windows only, and [xnviewmp](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is multiplatform. i havent played around with xnviewmp for a long time, i dont think you can set a custom image as the thumbnail. you can set thumbnail sizes under the browser though. most free image browsers offer a portable mode

Comment: to my knowledge, what you are after isn't available. however, i have a semi-complete application i made with WinAutomation that does just this. you select the parent folder, and then it iterates through each image folder. you pick the image you want as the folder icon, and it then generates the folder icon and configuration file. do you know how to make the config file? if not am happy to share

Comment: @faustus: thanks for the offer but I'm way too slow in programming. Maybe if you save it on github someone will pick it up and add that feature?

Comment: What you are asking for is not reasonable, applications doesn't manage/interact with the humbnails and layers of a multimedia folder icon (they could, but thet don't because there is no reason to do it), the Windows APIs does all the job. 
I think we will never see this in a commercial app because the lack of user-demand about the feature you are talking about, probably nobody requested this yet, then app developers probably didn't considered to change the common Windows thumbnail behavior, just because there is no reason to do it (it implies a hard job development, to satisfy what needs?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested XnViewMP and it has this feature. Instead of showing the folder thumbnails as a four image thumbnail, it can show just the thumb of the first image in the folder.

I've found a workaround for setting which image in the folder to be shown as the thumb - I can make a copy of the desired image so it will be the first image in that folder, and then it will be shown as the thumb for that folder.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.